# properly rendering an SDL rectangle to the screen

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, game-development

Here is my code, I am following lazyfoos tutorials on SDL, here is the exact tutorial I am following - http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/08_geometry_rendering/index.php

> Notice the call to SDL_SetRenderDrawColor. We're using 255 red and 255
>   green which combine together to make yellow. Remember that call to
>   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor at the top of the loop? If that wasn't there,
>   the screen would be cleared with whatever color was last set with
>   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor, resulting in a yellow background in this case.

Lazyfoo does explain it above but it still doesn't make sense to me.

To draw a filled rectangle to the screen is a pretty trivial task but it's a task that sometimes causes a lot of confusion,for example you need to call SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() not once but twice,once before you clear the renderer,and also once before you call SDL_RenderFillRect().

Why do you need to call SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() twice and why in that order? I noticed if I comment out the first SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() just before the call to SDL_RenderFillRect(),the full window will be the colour you set the rectangle to be,but when you include the two calls to SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() in the order I specified the window shows a coloured rectangle in the centre of the screen with the rest of the screen being white(first SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() call).

Here is my game loop where the calls are made.

```
while( !quit )
{
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) != 0 )
    {
        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            quit = true;

        }
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0 ); // line of code in question
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    SDL_Rect fillRect = { 500 / 4, 500 / 4, 500 / 2, 500 / 2 };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF ); // 2nd line of code in question
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect );

    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do you need to call SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() twice and why in that
>   order?

The name of `SDL_RenderClear` is a bit misleading. It doesn't clear the screen to "empty" or anything - it just fills it with whatever color was set by `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`. So if you don't change the color between "clearing" and drawing the rectangle, then you won't see the rectangle because you're drawing it with the same color that you just filled the entire screen with.

So here

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );
```

You make the whole screen white. We do this by setting white, and then painting over the entire screen with white.

Then here

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
```

We set red so the rectangle here

```
SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );
```

Will be red (not white).

And if I remember the tutorial correctly, it also draws a line and some other things, every time calling `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` right before to set the correct color.

> I noticed if I comment out the first SDL_SetRenderDrawColor() just
>   before the call to SDL_RenderFillRect(),the full window will be the
>   colour you set the rectangle to be

Very good observation! You see, since you're looping (`while(!quit){`) you do `SDL_RenderClear` and then `SDL_RenderFillRect`... but then `SDL_RenderClear` comes again, and so on. So when `SDL_RenderClear` happens, the color was actually set from right before `SDL_RenderFillRect` in the *last* run through the loop. Hence why it has that color, too.

So actually, I don't know what the color is at the very first time because it's not set yet (might be a default value of white, or something), but we probably can't see it because that's just on the first run through the loop anyway. So what happens roughly is:

```
...
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF );
SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect );
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF );
SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect ); 
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF );
SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect ); 
...
```

So you see, with only that second `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` call, both `SDL_RenderClear` and `SDL_RenderFillRect` will always draw in green, except the very first `SDL_RenderClear` call in the first frame.

Comment: that makes sense :), I think I have the general idea now, so
SDL_RenderClear(renderer) will draw the colour set by SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,255,255,0) to white, next 
SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect ) will fill the area we specified with our SDL_Rect to the colour made with the call to SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF ) which is green, but this only draws to the back buffer,then we call SDL_RenderPresent(renderer) which updates the front buffer(what we see) and the rectangle and background are displayed?

Comment: That's exactly right. Every draw operation (including clearing) draws with the last color that was set. So if we always set the color just before doing a draw, it's simple. Otherwise it can be complicated. Sometimes I forget to set a color correctly in a complicated sequence and then suddenly I get a red background because that's what some other shape somewhere else has been drawn with. :)